# Samsung Pass (fingerprint) SDK - cannot use password as fallback on Galaxy 6 devices

Tags: android, fingerprint, samsung-mobile-sdk

I use the Samsung Pass SDK (1.20) in order to authenticate users that have a Samsung Android device with a fingerprint scanner. I am required to enable the user to enter his/her password as an alternative to fingerprint scanning (same as in the Android lock-screen).

In Samsung devices running Android 5 - it works fine. The dialog is displayed with a button with the text "Backup password" and the user can enter the password to authenticate but in Android 6.0 and up - it doesn't work.

Using the function `isFeatureEnabled(DEVICE_FINGERPRINT_AVAILABLE_PASSWORD)` returns `false`.

It looks like Samsung has disabled this feature in Android 6 devices. I couldn't find anything in the docs about this.

Is there a reason for that? more importantly, are there any workarounds (not hacks of course)?

Thanks!

Comment: researching same thing right now - still no answer

Comment: Does anyone got the solution for this answer ? please share it here if found. Thanks.

Comment: From what iv'e seen - in Android 6 this option is disabled for Samsung devices completely. No change in Android N from what iv'e seen. 
I would assume it's in order to align the Samsung fingerprint SDK with the Google native fingerprint api that was introduced in Android M.